# Build.VERSION.SDK_INT doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

For an SDK higher than version 21, I use a specific layout.
For the lower versions I have an extra object for the ripple effect and I differentiate the layouts in my code by this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            RippleView rippleView1 = (RippleView) findViewById(R.id.ripple1);
...
}
```

But when I compile on Android M, I get this error:

```
Error:(45, 68) error: cannot find symbol variable ripple1.
```

If I add this object in my layout-v21, I no longer have this error and I use this object only in this if.
My question is: how does Android enter this statement while I am on a version higher than 21?

Comment: Because the whole code is compiled and evaluated? Sections are not "removed" just because you have an if statement

Comment: @cricket_007 ok, so how can I make it not evaluated if my sdk> 21?

Comment: Why can't you define `ripple1` id elsewhere?

Comment: I can define it but it is unused so I wanted to know how to make this statement not be interpreted in all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new file `res/values/ids.xml`

```
<resources>
    <item name="ripple1" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

And in the layout `android:id="@id/ripple1"` (remove the plus).

In the Java code, keep the if statement. Should compile okay.